# XPATH - Grab Information from divs in flat html structure

Tags: html, xpath

I a really struggling to grab the information from the divs in this loop. Can anyone shed any light on this at all? At the moment I am using the context of:

**//li[@class=' review_tr']**

and the following stuff is working fine:

```
//span[@id='hp_hotel_name'] - hotel name
.//p[@class='comments_good'] - positive review
.//p[@class='comments_bad'] - negative review
```

But I cannot grab any other field such as:

```
<div class="name"> - reviewer name
<div class="location"> - reviewer location
<div class="user_type"> - user type.
```

Does anyone know how I can grab these three fields?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<li id="747282424" class=" review_tr">
<div class="cell_user"
alt="hotel Review - Mature couple"
>
<div class="user_profile_wrapper"><div class="user_profile_avatar">
<div class="review_avatar mature couple">
<!--

--> 

</div>
</div></div> 
<div class="user_profile">
<div class="name">
Anonymous
</div>
<div class="user_type">
Mature couple
</div>
<div class="location">

Switzerland
</div>
<div class="date">24 March 2013</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="speech_bubble_container"><div class="speech_bubble">
<div class="cell_comments">
<div id="area_comments_747282424">
<p class="comments_good" lang="en">
Located at 5 minutes walk from Petronas Towers and with many bars and
restaurant around. Very large room with all the needed comfort. Fast and
free wifi. Free parking. Free toproof pool with great view.
</p>
<!-- Start review_no_thumbs.inc -->
<div class="no_thumbs">

<span class="vote_copy">
Did you find this review helpful?
</span>
<span class="review_feedback">
<form class="review_useful_form" action="/feedback?type=review_feedback&amp;comment=1&amp;object_id=747282424&amp;hotel_id=175845" method="post">
<!-- 175845 -->
<!-- 175845 -->
<button class="review_no_thumbs_yes"  type="submit">yes</button>
</form>
<form class="review_useful_form" action="/feedback?type=review_feedback&amp;comment=0&amp;object_id=747282424&amp;hotel_id=175845" method="post">
<button class="review_no_thumbs_no"  type="submit">no</button>
</form>
</span>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

<!-- End review_no_thumbs.inc -->
</div>
</div>
<div class="cell_score">
<span class="the_score">9.6</span>
</div>
</div></div>
<hr class="clearfix" />
</li>
```

Comment: Hmm, why not `//div[@class='name']`?

Comment: `//li[@class=' review_tr']//div[@class='name']` works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the same logic in which you got those positive and negative reviews:

You can match whatever `div` is in there with the class `name`:

```
.//div[@class='name']
```

Or navigate it in more detail so that you don't get a `div` with the class `name` that could be, for instance, outside of the `cell_user` `div`:

```
./div[@class='cell_user']/div[@class='user_profile']/div[@class='name']
```

Getting the `location` and `user_type` `div`s should be a trivial task.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have tried that and also thought it would be simple but this won't grab the information. I have tried every combination I can think of plus the one you give in your response and the 3 divs I mention are not returned.

Comment: Then there is something else going on... I've tested this [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: I cannot work out how to use the tester so cannot check using that. Really cannot figure this one out. Thanks for your help, I think I'll have to pay someone to do this for me.

Comment: Haha, it is simple. On the top left textarea paste the content of the `li` that you have in the question. On the top right textarea paste the XPath expression I gave you (only one). Select XPath 2.0 from the radio buttons in there too. The result will automatically appear in the textarea on the bottom :)

Comment: Done that and this area is blank: Result of the above expression applied to the above html file:

Comment: This has to be something to do with the context I am using for this thing: //li[@class=' review_tr'

Comment: Well, I did notice something that I didn't mention because I thought it could have been some kind of glitch in the page, but maybe it helps: try matching `//li[@class=" review_tr"]` and then remove the space before `review_tr`

Comment: I'll give that a go, just that there's a space in the actual code so I thought I'd leave it in! Cheers.